# Prototype javascript not working properly

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am using prototype JavaScript library 1.7.2 in my project.But when i open in IE11 its give me below error for createElement code of JavaScript. Also not working in other browser. Only IE11 debugger show this error

code : `var el = document.createElement('<input name="x">');`

Error : **InvalidCharacterError**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's native client-side Javascript, so it seems unrelated to PrototypeJS to me. The [correct syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) is

```
var el = document.createElement('input');
el.name = "x";
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I know correct syntax for create input element but in prototype js HAS_EXTENDED_CREATE_ELEMENT_SYNTAX function create input element using above syntax. Can i change code in prototype js ?

Comment: Seems that Microsoft removed support for their proprietary `createElement` syntax in IE9. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986077(v=vs.85).aspx). What's more, it seems that [their documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536389(v=vs.85).aspx) is not up-to-date, i.e. there's a discrepancy between the description of the example code and the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

To create elements like you are referring to in PrototypeJS you would do it like this :

`var el = new Element('input',{'name':'x'});`

This will work across all browsers that PrototypeJS supports